# How relate the length of a conveyor belt between two interlocked circles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Two wheels are one next to another and linked by a conveyor belt. How to express the length of the radius of the smaller wheel in terms of the length of the belt? Note that the size of the radius of A is three times the radius of B.

[image: Sketch of the problem (not in scale)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the length of the belt be $b$.

[image]

\begin{align} 
d&=\sqrt{(4r)^2-(2r)^2}
=2\sqrt{3}r
,\\
\phi&=\arccos\tfrac{2r}{4r}=\tfrac\pi3
,\\
b&=2\,((\pi-\phi)\cdot3r+d+\phi\,r)
\\
&=2(2\pi r+2\sqrt{3}r+\tfrac\pi3 r)
\\
&=(\tfrac{14}3 \pi +4\sqrt{3})r
,\\
r&=\frac{b}{\tfrac{14}3 \pi +4\sqrt{3}}
.
\end{align}

Comment: Mind sharing what software did you used to sketch the graphics and label the angles and the lenghts?. Plus, how can be proved that the $PO_{1}O_{2}$ angle formed on the bigger wheel and $BO_{2}$ in the smaller one are the same?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell The software appears to be $\LaTeX$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I am not very fond of Latex use in geometry. Do you happen to know any documentation where can I learn how geometry is supported on Latex?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell [Share$\LaTeX$](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn)

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor The documentation provided does not seem to give insight on how to draw euclidean geometry, however there is this site http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/ which does seem to support graphics but I'm not sure if its what the answerer has used in his answer.

Comment: @Chris Steinbeck Bell: 
The drawing was made with the [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/),
"a powerful descriptive 2D and 3D vector graphics language 
that provides a natural coordinate-based framework for technical drawing. 
Labels and equations are typeset with LaTeX, for high-quality PostScript output."
It is also part of the TeXLive distribution.

Comment: @Chris Steinbeck Bell: $O_1A || O_2 B$.

Comment: @g.kov Thanks that explained a lot. I was not aware such software existed. It will come in handy for next time if required.

Comment: @g.kov Can you take a look into this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458271/how-to-find-the-perimeter-of-a-triangle-which-connects-three-circles? The answer there is not sufficient to let me understand. I would appreciate your help with that one.