# How to find the perimeter of a triangle which connects three circles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

The figure from below show three circles, T and P are tangential points and A, B and C are the center of each circle. How can I find the perimeter of the triangle ABC if the distance between AC is 7 centimeters?.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

Edit:

Can it be proved that the line joining the points T, B, and A is a straight line? Because the smaller circle with center at B is not in scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's draw the tangent lines 
$\ell_p$ and $\ell_t$
through the points $P,T$, $\ell_p \cap \ell_t=Q$.

[image]

Note that $\ell_p$ is tangent to both circles $B$ and $C$,
similarly, $\ell_t$ is tangent to both circles $B$ and $A$,
and $BQ$ is a bisector of $\angle PQT$.

Hence 
\begin{align}
BT&\subset AT,\quad |BT|=|BP|=r\in(0,\tfrac12R]
,\\ 
|AB|&=R-r,
\end{align}

and a variable part of the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$,
$|AB|+|BP|=R$.

**Edit**

The locus of all centers of the circles $B$,
that touch one of the other two circles ($A,B$)
internally, and the other one externally,
is an ellipse $\mathcal{E}$.
The smallest (degenerate) such circle with $r=0$
is centered at $H_1,H_2$,
the biggest one with $r=\tfrac12R$ is 
centered at points $G_1,G_2$, in which case 
the lines $\ell_1\parallel\ell_2$ and the point $Q$
is at the infinity.

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for redrawing the problem but I'm stuck at trying to understand, What's the purpose of creating a point Q which is outside the boundaries of both circles?, how does it help to solve the problem?. Why r is between 0 and $\frac{1}{2}$. I'm good with the rest, as it can be concluded that the perimeter becomes $3R$, its just those things I mentioned at the beginning which I don't understand.

Comment: Mind If you could explain the necessity of point Q and why the radius r belongs to the interval 0 and $\frac{1}{2}R$. This part I'm confused.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: See the update.

Comment: I am having problems at understanding the way how you're using the concept of degenerate. By doing a research on my own, degenerate in a circle means a point right?. Thus radius is zero but how does this translates as centered in $H_{1} and H_{2}$? The other part is easier because if the smaller radius grows bigger to become half of the larger radius then both lines will be parallel but how this second part translates as being centered at $G_{1} and G_{2}$?. I'm stuck at this.

Comment: If you could add a second picture to explain the part about H and G would be perfect as much information in the same picture can be confusing. Sorry if this makes you work twice but I want to learn.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: See the animation.

Comment: Neat and nice! Now I can see and understand what were you talking about. Thanks for adding that animation.

Comment: Can you help me with this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571945/how-to-find-length-difference-between-two-tangential-points-of-a-circle-inscribe/2571996#2571996 ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Notice that $$\bar{AB} = \bar{AT}-\bar{BT}$$,
$$\bar{BC}=\bar{BP}+\bar{PC}$$
So the perimeter is $$P=\bar{AC}+\bar{AB}+\bar{BC}$$
Replacing,$$P=\bar{AC}+\bar{AT}-\bar{BT}+\bar{BP}+\bar{PC}$$.
Also notice that $\bar{BT}=\bar{BP}$ (radii of the same circle), $\bar{AT}=\bar{AC}=\bar{PC}$, so
$$P=3\bar{AC}$$
$$P=21cm$$

Comment: I think in this situation it would be much better if the solution can accompany a drawing with labels inside as reading equations is not that too obvious. There is also, how can I tell or prove that the line TA is straight and also passes through B?.

Comment: I could try using a picture to solve this problem. With respect to your question, I just take it like a fact from the picture.

Comment: To take it like a fact from the picture is not obvious as the circles are not in scale. That's why I asked how to prove that.

Comment: Hmm. That's a difficult problem to solve. Maybe you could ask someone else for help.Nevertheless, I'll try to prove it.

Comment: I also agree its difficult. If you come up with a proof please leave a feedback.