# How to find length difference between two tangential points of a circle inscribed in a triangle?

Tags: geometry

The problem is as follows:

M, N and Q are tangential points, if $\overline{AB}=9\,cm$ and $\overline{BC}=40\,cm$ What is the value of $\overline{CM}-\overline{AN}$.

[image: Diagram of the problem]

I'm stuck on this problem. So far I have identified that there might be a relationship between $CM$ and $CQ$ and as well between $BN$ and $BQ$ however I have not yet the sufficient knowledge to go beyond this point to solve this question.

Since i'm not too familiar with line segment notation an answer which would use instead letters as variables be more helpful. Also there is the fact that as any geometry question a new graph with labels on top would provide a better explanation on how to address this problem. Taken this into consideration, What would be the way to solve this problem?

Comment: $$CM-AN = CQ-AN = (CQ+BQ)-(AN+BN) = BC-AB = 31.$$ $\widehat{A}=90^\circ$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Your answer might be right. But I don't get the idea without a drawing which would explain what's going on and why those relationships stands.

Comment: You already have a drawing and $$AM=AN,\quad CM=CQ,\quad BN=BQ $$ are trivial: join the incenter with its projections on the sides and the vertices $A,B,C$ and $ABC$ is partitioned in six right triangles sharing the length of a leg (the inradius).

Comment: Why is it hard to make a drawing including with labels such as the radius and proofs as any solution of geometry has?

Comment: Again, you already have a drawing. Can you figure, on such drawing, why $$AM=AN,\quad CM=CQ,\quad BN=BQ $$ are trivial?

Comment: The drawing I made is insufficient to prove why tangential points make those segments equal. A redrawn figure with explanations would be much helpful rather than to read line segments which can be misleading to understand if the OP is not very fond on geometry and wants to learn step by step what's going on and more importantly why? Moreover even if is taken for granted that line segments are fine (which the OP has stated would understand better to not use them), it does not make it clear as how the final answer is $31$.

Comment: Let $\Gamma$ be a circle centered at $O$ and let $P$ be a point outside $\Gamma$. Assume that $A,B\in\Gamma$ and $PA,PB$ are tangent to $\Gamma$: then $PA=PB$. This is a well-known lemma, very simple to prove (the configuration is symmetric with respect to the $PO$ line), also in your diagram.

Comment: Using [this diagram](https://imgur.com/a/k7Y8M) as a reference, it is pretty clear that $BC-AB=(\color{green}{\text{green}}+\color{blue}{\text{blue}})-(\color{green}{\text{green}}+\color{red}{\text{red}})=\color{blue}{\text{blue}}-\color{red}{\text{red}}=CM-AN.$

Comment: Going back at your proposed solution it is not clear how $CQ-AN=(CQ+BQ)-(AN+BN)$ If I would just replace the relationships merely algebraic (which is not the case). That would meant suddenly $CQ$ becomes into $CQ+BQ$ and $AN$ into $AN+BN$. Does that make sense? The lemma you had just stated wouldn't fail if $A,B$ are too close to each other and $P$ is situated on the opposite side of the circle $\gamma$?. Yet if I take the lemma as a (dogma, which is a no-no in mathematics), it does only "solve" one part of your solution. I drawn this sketch using inkscape but I'm sure there are better tools..

Comment: The reference is much appreciated but how does the $90^o$ is irrelevant?. So excluding colors do I get the idea $BC=CM$ and $AB=AN$? does this really make sense?.

Comment: If $x=y$, $$ (a+x)-(b+y) = (a+x)-(b+x) = (a-b).$$ And there is no *dogma*: http://www.9math.com/book/tangents-circle-are-equal-length

Comment: In mathematical reasoning (geometry, algebra, or any other kind), it's wrong to just ignore some parts of a theorem's conditions when proposing counterexamples. You propose to put $A$ and $B$ on the "opposite side" of the circle from $P$; how do you do that, and still satisfy the condition that $PA$ and $PB$ are tangent to the circle?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Not mean to bash your efforts but as a student the problem at understanding is not solved by adding colors and state "its pretty clear" but rather making own self understood how to get from a proposed statement to the solution of the problem. In this case I tried unsuccessfully to follow your method. The only thing that seems clear is the sides tangent to the circle are the same, but it does not mean all are equal rather the adjacent ones are. With this method is not possible to find what is $CM$ or $BN$ individually but rather is only possible to find the difference between. .

Comment: Like [De Giorgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ennio_de_Giorgi) once said, *trivial is a subjective concept, but this is really trivial, my dear students*.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio To reach to this "explanation" a redrawn figure with labels on top explicitly would be needed. I got to the $31$ by building up a system of $2\times2$ of let's say $CM=a$ and $AN=b$ and $BN=c$, since $a+c=40$ and $b+c=9$, we're asked to find which is the value of $a-b$. Therefore by solving the earlier system we can get to $a-b=31$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Was that hard to understand?. It wasn't, but probably the thing is, when somebody tries to make himself understood is looking at the problem behind the perspective of a mathematician and not from somebody who does see these things as a challenge or something which is unfamiliar and to reach that only explicit sketches are the way to go.

Comment: Tangents to a circle from an external point have equal lengths. This is well-known, not difficult to prove, easy to study through the given link. Equality is transitive and $(a+x)-(b+x)=(a-b)$. If colors do not help, just ignore them, but you already have all the elements for writing a rigorous proof the the claim $CM-AN=31$, which is summarized by my very first comment. I think to have provided enough help, even for a problem which completely lacks actual attempts, so, with or without your explicit permission, I am disengaging from this conversation.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Since this question is on hold nobody can add answers. But had you come (maybe earlier?) could had put all of those as an answer or proposed one would had been much better. It seems I have not made myself understood, is reliance on tex an excuse for diverting explanations given in other places or just means to come on by help given the limitations of comments.I tend to believe the latter. I got what you meant by the proof of tangents,it does apply and its no brainer. But to make it no brainer had been nicer to see it in the problem rather than compare it from an external source

Comment: Btw the imgur looks nice had been a great addition but it didn't make it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ be the inradius of triangle ABC. The sides mentioned are - $a$ is the side opposite to angle $A$ and so on. Now we want the value of  $ CM-AN=AC-AM-AN =AC-2AN =  b - 2r$ (because of the square, $AN = r =AM$ ).  We already know $a, c$ and hence $b$ (by Pythagoras) and area of triangle ABC( let this be $K = bc/2$ ) is known so we get $r$ by formula $r = K/s$.

Now we know all three sides (Pythagoras) hence area(half base$ *$height) and semiperimeter, s(half of sum of sides).

As we know area($K$)  and semiperimeter($s$) , we calculate inradius, $r=K/s$ and subtract  twice of it from b to get the answer.

Comment: I tried to follow your directions but if you on by that route is not easy to compute the value of the hypotenuse without the help of a calculator. The other part which you were referring about the area of the triangle I dont know how does it supposed to help with the solution of the problem?.

Comment: We can't help the data given in the question so use of calculator would be unavoidable. Area is used to find r, twice of which in turn is subtracted from b to find the answer. A= bc/2  (half base into height)

Comment: i'm a little slow at trying to understand the part of why do we want $b-2r$? Where does $2r$ come from?. I understand the $r$ you are referring to is the inradius but the other part is where I'm lost at.

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. $CM-AN=CA-MA-AN=AC-2AM=b-2r$

Comment: The result of the other side by Pitagorean theorem is $7\sqrt{31}$ The $s$ you mentioned in the area what is it?. Again it is not very clear on how does the area helps to solve this. Either way the area needs the base of the triangle. Provided you use the smaller base, means $a$ and $b$. Therefore $9\times\frac{7\sqrt{31}}{2}$ is the area. Still not very clear.

Comment: We do not use $a$ and $b$, rather we use perpendicular lengths to find area $\frac{b*c} {2}$.  Area is used to find inradius r, what is not clear in that?

Comment: Probably it is much better to state which is $b$, $c$ and $a$ before continuing to develop the latter ideas. Are you using the notation which was given by other people or making one your own?. Then going on with the solution. The other side of the triangle (not the hypotenuse) is $7\sqrt{31}$ then you mention to find the area. Of what?. The triangle ? Why? We already know their sides, unless you're referring to other triangle. The inradius is needed as means of your method but is not clear how it is linked to the area. Perhaps you should write explicitly what you meant.

Comment: I've mentioned the definition of a, b, c. Area is of triangle ABC, to calculate it's inradius. It is a common formula relating area, semiperimeter and inradius as mentioned above.

Comment: If you're asking for a proof of this formula, join centre of the incircle(let $O) to all the sides and you'll get three triangles, ie. OAB, OBC, OAC. Now the three sides are tangent to circle hence perpendicular from circle on the sides is equal to $r$. Now area of triangle ABC is sum of area of three triangles$ =(1/2)(r*a+r*b+r*c) =r*s=K$ hence $r=K/s$.