# Trigonometry in isoceles trisected triangles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

**Hello,**

> A $\triangle ABC$ has a point $D$ on $BC$ such that $\angle BAD = 30$ and $\angle CAD = 45$. Both $AB$ and $AC$ are of the length $\sqrt{2}$. Find the length of $AD$.[image]

This is what I have done:-

Taking $AD$ as $x$ and $DC$ as $y$, and then using law of cosines for $y$, we get $y^2 = 2 + x^2 - 2x$.

Taking $BD$ as $k$, and applying law of cosines on $k$, we get $k^2 = x^2 + 2 - x*root6$

Taking law of cosines on $k + y$ we get, $(k + y)^2 = 5 - root3 ( cos 75 = root3 - 1/ 2*root2)$

And now I'm stuck at this step. I have no idea on how to go forward after this step.

**ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED(if possible in trigonometry plz).**

*This is not a part of the question but can someone give me a link for the quick reference of mathjax editing?*

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/122782).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Since $|AB|=|AC|$,

\begin{align} 
\angle ACD&=\angle ABD=52.5^\circ
,\\
\angle DAB&=97.5^\circ
,\\
\angle ADC&=82.5^\circ
.
\end{align}

Using the standard notation for $\triangle ABC$,
the area $[ABC]$ in terms of known side $a$ and 
the angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ is 
\begin{align} 
[ABC]&=\frac{a^2\sin\beta\sin\gamma}{2\sin\alpha}
.\\
\text{Then}\quad[ADC] \text{ in terms of } |AC|:\quad
[ADC]&=\frac{(\sqrt2)^2\sin52.5^\circ\sin45^\circ}{2\sin82.5^\circ}
=\frac{\sin52.5^\circ}{\sin82.5^\circ}
,\\
\text{and}\quad[ADC] \text{ in terms of } x:\quad
[ADC]&=\frac{x^2\sin82.5^\circ\sin45^\circ}{2\sin52.5^\circ}
=
\frac{x^2\sin82.5^\circ}{2\sin52.5^\circ}
,\\
x&=\frac{\sqrt2\sin52.5^\circ}{\sin82.5^\circ}
.
\end{align}

**Edit:**

\begin{align} 
x&=\frac{\sqrt2\sin52.5^\circ}{\sin82.5^\circ}
\\
&=\sqrt2\cdot\frac{\sin(82.5^\circ-30^\circ)}{\sin82.5^\circ}
\\
&=\sqrt2\left(\cos30^\circ 
-\sin30^\circ\cot82.5^\circ
\right)
\\
&=\sqrt2\left(\tfrac{\sqrt3}2 
-\tfrac12\tan(\tfrac{30^\circ}4)
\right)
\\
&=\sqrt2\left(\tfrac{\sqrt3}2 
-\tfrac12(\sqrt2\sqrt3-\sqrt3+\sqrt2-2)
\right)
\\
&=(\sqrt2-1)(1+\sqrt3)
.
\end{align}

Comment: Very sorry, i gave the wrong angle specification, can you plz check the question again and give me the answer

Comment: Can you please tell me how you got sin 52.5/sin 82.5 in the 3rd step. Also can you please send me a link for the identity if you used it.

Comment: Can you please tell me which software you used to draw that diagram?

Comment: @Adithya Dsilva: [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/),
see also the comments to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2456737/122782).

Answer (score 1):

Answer to a changed problem.

The easiest way to solve the problem is with introduction of the coordinate system. Let $A=(0,0)$ and $D=(0,d)$. We have to find $d$. Then $AC$ is a line $y=x$ and $AB$ is a line $y=-{\sqrt{3}\over 3}x$. Since $B,C$ lies on the circle $x^2+y^2=2$ we can easily calculate coordinate of $B$ and $C$:

$$ B = ({\sqrt{6}\over 2},-{\sqrt{2}\over 2})\;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\; C = (1,1)$$ Since $B,C,D$ are colinear we get $$d= (\sqrt{3}+1)(\sqrt{2}-1)$$

Comment: Any trigonometric method? And what's the length of AD? because the answers are integer type and the length of AD is in the form root m/2. We have to give the value of m and I thought I needn't bother this community for such simple simplifications.